# ADO.NET EF - can't connect to my DB (using Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net-entity-data-model

So I'm struggling with this problem for more than 4 hours and I don't know where to look at any more. I follow this tutorial for absolute beginners in `ADO.NET Entity Framework` - [See The tutorial][1]  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542 
I'm using `Microsoft SQL Server 2012` and I'm using this `App.Config` file for my project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=sqlserver2012; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

But I keep getting errors and when I use this code the error is : `**An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string.**`

I'm totally new to `ADO.NET Entity Framework` but as I see it the problem maybe is in `defaultConnectionFactory` configuration. But anyways I can't find out how to keep on and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you in fact have SQL Server instance named sqlserver2012 on your localhost zour connectionString should look like this

```
<parameter value="Data Source=localhost\sqlserver2012; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Cheers,
T.